# How to create a website with a searchbar to query a mongo database?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a large mongoDB database set up and am trying to create a website where a user can use a searchbar to query the database remotely and have the results posted on the site (strictly read-only).

I have experience with databases for data analysis, but have never created a website for querying results.

I'm don't have any experience with web development and don't know what platforms (PHP? node.js?) to use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are the following steps to the problem:

1. Create the front-end, which will consist of HTML, CSS, and Javascript. Beginners often find it easiest to work with jQuery and jQuery UI, because they are well-documented and contain plugins for almost all possible scenarios (they should not, however, be used to create large complex applications!). Bootstrap or Foundation can help you with the HTML / CSS.
2. Create a (probably) JSON API, which the front-end can communicate with to submit searches and retrieve results. You could use PHP, Python, Ruby, or many other languages to do this. For a simple site like the one you're describing, it's more a matter of preference than anything else.
3. Translate the search request from the front-end into the MongoDB query APIs, and return the results through the API. You will use a MongoDB client library compatible with whatever language you have chosen.

Depending on your needs, you may be able to eliminate (2) by using an existing [REST API for MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/).

Note that if you just want to make MongoDB data accessible via searching / charting, then you may be able to avoid coding altogether by leveraging [SlamData](http://slamdata.com), an open source project I contribute to. SlamData lets you use Google-style search (or more advanced SQL) to query MongoDB and get the results back in tabular or chart form.

Comment: I took a look at SlamData and it looks interesting. Is it primarily an administrator/site management tool or can it also be easily modified for front-end user usage?

Comment: It's primarily intended for front-end users, although you can use it for light admin (it does not have the ability to modify the data so it's better for end-users than admins).

Comment: Looks like slamdata is no longer open source?

Answer (score 2):

I am doing such in nodejs.

In my server side app I have connection via mognoose like:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://yourhost/database');
```

Next you need to have your model to your database

```
var YourDBVarName = mongoose.model('collectionName', {
  yourfields1 : type,
  yourfields2 : type,
  yourfields3 : type
  ...
});
```

Then I make GET for it

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/dblisting', function(req,res){
   YourDBVarName.find({ yourfieldsX: 'value'}, function(err, data) {
      if(err) {
         res.send(err.message);
      }
      else{
        res.send(data);
      });
});
```

Then simply you make some GET with $.ajax to yournodeserver.com/dblisting and in response you recive your collection filtered as in

```
{ yourfieldsX: 'value'}
```

Ofcourse you may do just {} so you get all your stored data.

Comment: Oh, and as well you should secure it by user authorize. You can make users collection similar to above and use express-session + connect-mongo + cookies-parse :) This info is enough to google it :)

Answer (score 1):

SLee
If you want know about retrieving data from mongoDB, you can use my github https://github.com/parthaindia/CustomMongo .Use getByCondition() method which requires collection name and a Map . The Map can be your queries in form of key value pair,Key being the column name. I use this method when I write search Query for the web development. The java code gives you a Json. Write a Servlet to post your Json to WEB UI.

This is an example to show how to post the retrieved data using Js  ,"server_base_url + /server/FetchData" would be your Service URL.The data you has to be appended to a table . Or a span ,depends on what you actually want.The below code appends data

function getdata() {

```
$.get(server_base_url + "/server/FetchData", {
}).done(function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        alert("The Index" + index + "The Value" + value);
          $("#11table1").append("<tr><td id='dynamicid1" + index + "'>" + value + "</td></tr>");
    });

});
```

}

This function can be used for defining table

function defineTable() {

```
$("#mainDivID").text("").append("<div id='contpanel' class='contentpanel'>");
$("#contpanel").append("<div id='rowid11' class='row'>");
$("#rowid11").text("").append("<div id='row11table1' class='col-md-12'>");
$("#row11table1").text("").append('<br /><br /><center><h5 class="lg-title mb5" style="background-color:#428BCA;height:20px;color:#fff;padding-top:4px;"><b>Heading</b></h5></center>');
$("#row11table1").append("<div id='table11id1' class='table-responsive'>");
$("#table11id1").append("<table id='11table1' class='table table table-bordered mb30' >");
$("#11table1").append("<thead><tr><th>Index</th><th>Value</th></tr></thead>");
```

}