# I am trying to query mongoDB by having the user enter a name in a search box, then finding all documents that match that search

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

The code I have so far allows me to query the database by finding a specific key:value in the documents, but I want to be able to pass an argument into the function so that the user's search becomes the 'value' in the key:value query. Currently, I have "Cosmic Black" in place of where I want the user's argument to be.

```
var findMaterials = function(db, callback) {
    var cursor = db.collection('materials').find( {"material_name": "Cosmic Black"} );
    cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        if (doc !== null) {
            console.log(doc);
        } else {
            callback();
        }
    });
};
```

I just don't know how to get the argument in there, or if it's even possible with the current code setup. Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: How are your running your script?  Are you typing node <scriptname> via the command line, or does this run when you hit a specific url endpoint?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a website with a searchbar to query a mongo database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31176349/how-to-create-a-website-with-a-searchbar-to-query-a-mongo-database)

Comment: Right now were in development, so just running through command line, but ultimately it will be specific endpoint

Answer (score 0):

```
var findMaterials = function(db, value, callback) {
    var cursor = db.collection('materials').find( {"material_name": value} );
    cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        if (doc !== null) {
            console.log(doc);
        } else {
            callback();
        }
    });
};
```

How you're calling findMaterials(), that's a different question. Something like this should do the trick.

```
function doAllTheWork(url, value){
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) { 
        assert.equal(null, err); 
        findMaterials(db, value, function() { 
            db.close(); 
        }); 
    });
}
```

Pass value as some sort of param.  If you're building an API pluck it out of the JSON.  If you're running all this from the cmd line then just do the same via that methodology.

Comment: MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
 assert.equal(null, err);
 findMaterials(db, function() {
  db.close();
 });
});

Comment: @MattP something like above?